# C# windows phone - combine audio and video file

Tags: c#, windows, audio, video, windows-phone

I'm building an app where I need to combine audio and video files, I'm able to record  the video but  I have to replace the original audio with an audio file I have on the phone, so the question is: how can I combine audio and video in windows phone with c#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: I modified the question, sorry I didn't know

Comment: Ok geniuses, so where can we find an answer to this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using MediaComposition object in Windows.Media.Editing.

With this class you can add a BackgroundAudioTrack in a video.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.editing.aspx